# How can I make an element lose it's box-model?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm using VueJS and have nested elements which are dynamically created like so:

```
<container>
  <outerElement class="outer" v-for="obj in objects">
    <innerElement class="inner" v-for="element in obj"/>
  </outerElement>
</container>
```

Now when it comes to CSS I'm having a slight problem. Since the innerElements are intended to be moveable, they need the outer element to have the same size/position as the container.

**Is there some way in CSS to remove the box-model from the 'outer' class whilst remaining in the container?**

Here's a sketch of what I'm trying to achieve.
[image: sketch]

---

### EDIT:

To fix the mentioned XY-Problem, here is the template in a simplified version, using the same implementation methods as in my application.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <h1>This is the main Page.</h1>

    <h2>Testing area:</h2>
    <br />Simple Data Example:
    <br />
    <div class="container">
      <button @click="simpleXOR()">XOR</button>
      {{ data }}
      <vue-draggable-resizable
        class="simple"
        v-for="(bit,index) in simpleData"
        :key="index"
        :w="50"
        :h="50"
        :parent="true"
        :resizable="false"
      >
        {{`Bit-${index} => `}}
        <status-indicator :status="bit ? 'positive' : 'negative'" />
      </vue-draggable-resizable>
    </div>
    <br />Nested Data Example
    <div class="container">
      <div class="outer" v-for="obj in nestedObj.data" :key="obj.name">
        <div class="label">
          <button @click="nestedXOR(obj.name)">XOR -> {{ obj.name }}</button>
          {{ obj.states }}
        </div>
        <vue-draggable-resizable
          class="inner"
          v-for="(state, index) in obj.states"
          :key="index"
          :resizable="false"
          :w="100"
          :h="50"
          :parent="true"
        >
          <div v-if="obj.contentType === 'TypeA'">
            <b>{{ `Bit-${index} of ${obj.name}` }}</b>
            <br />
            <status-indicator :status="state ? 'positive' : 'negative'" />
          </div>
          <div v-else>
            <b>{{ `Bit-${index} of ${obj.name}` }}</b>
            <br />
            <status-indicator :status="state ? 'active' : 'intermediary'" />
          </div>
        </vue-draggable-resizable>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src

export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      simpleData: [0, 1, 0, 1],
      nestedObj: {
        data: [
          {
            states: [0, 1, 0, 1],
            name: "a",
            contentType: "TypeA"
          },
          {
            states: [0, 1, 0, 1],
            name: "b",
            contentType: "TypeB"
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    data() {
      return this.simpleData;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    simpleXOR() {
      var x = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.simpleData.length; i++) {
        x.push(this.simpleData[i] ^ 1);
      }
      this.simpleData = x;
      console.debug(this.simpleData);
    },
    nestedXOR(name) {
      var index = this.nestedObj.data.findIndex(obj => {
        return obj.name === name;
      });
      var x = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.nestedObj.data[index].states.length; i++) {
        x.push(this.nestedObj.data[index].states[i] ^ 1);
      }
      this.nestedObj.data[index].states = x;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.container {
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.simple {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.outer {
  display: contents; /* as suggested */
}
.inner {
  /* ??? */
}
.label {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
}
/* // This is the css for vue-draggable-resizable */
/* // DON'T EDIT unless customization is needed */
.vdr {
  touch-action: none;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.handle {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.handle-tl {
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  cursor: nw-resize;
}
.handle-tm {
  top: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  cursor: n-resize;
}
.handle-tr {
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  cursor: ne-resize;
}
.handle-ml {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  left: -10px;
  cursor: w-resize;
}
.handle-mr {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  right: -10px;
  cursor: e-resize;
}
.handle-bl {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  cursor: sw-resize;
}
.handle-bm {
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  cursor: s-resize;
}
.handle-br {
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  cursor: se-resize;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  [class*="handle-"]:before {
    content: "";
    left: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;
    top: -10px;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
</style>
```

Currently the problem in this code is that the innerElements can't be moved inside the container, because the outerElement is their container.

Since I can't change the parent selector to use the container instead of the outerElement this is hard to change.

Thus I wanted to make the outerElements borders non-existant so that the innerElement uses the container as parent.

But I suppose my thought is a bit weird, considering that the vue-draggable-resizable component will use the outerElement as parent anyways.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:
[image: screenshot]

The moveable boxes can't be moved inside the container because the outerElement doesn't inherit the position and size of the container.

Comment: Right now your outer and inner are on the same level. Your indentation is wrong.

Comment: Heh, missed that.

Comment: By "on top of each other", do you mean "Only one can be visible at a time"? If so, use `display: none` on all the `<outerElement>` entries, and use `display: block` for the "active" one.

Comment: Sort of. They can both be visible. The outer act as a border for the innerElements which can be moved around. It would be straightforward if I didn't have dynamic outerElements, because then the border automatically would be that of the container. But with how it is currently the outerElements don't have the same borders.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please explain what you're trying to achieve. Anyways, the classical way of placing multiple elements at the same location is to give all of them `position: absolute` while wrapping them in a parent with `position:relative`. Please note that the parent should either have a min-width or any other mechanism preventing it from collapsing (since the contents are out of the document flow, it doesn't have any height).

Comment: I adjusted the question to fix the mentioned XY Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your simple example, you could just [flatten the nested array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) before iterating over it:

```html
<container>
  <innerElement class="inner" v-for="element in objects.flat(1)" />
</container>
```

The more complex example you posted is a bit trickier, since the inner loop also needs access to `obj`.  Still, you could do it by writing a custom method that wraps each state in an wrapper that contains both the state and a reference to the object it belongs to, like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="label" v-for="obj in nestedObj.data" :key="obj.name">
    <button @click="nestedXOR(obj.name)">XOR -> {{ obj.name }}</button>
    {{ obj.states }}
  </div>

  <vue-draggable-resizable
    class="inner"
    v-for="wrapper in flattenStates(nestedObj.data)"
    :key="wrapper.key"
    :resizable="false"
    :w="100"
    :h="50"
    :parent="true"
  >
    <div v-if="wrapper.obj.contentType === 'TypeA'">
      <b>{{ `Bit-${wrapper.index} of ${wrapper.obj.name}` }}</b>
      <br />
      <status-indicator :status="wrapper.state ? 'positive' : 'negative'" />
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <b>{{ `Bit-${wrapper.index} of ${wrapper.obj.name}` }}</b>
      <br />
      <status-indicator :status="wrapper.state ? 'active' : 'intermediary'" />
    </div>
  </vue-draggable-resizable>
</div>
```

where the `flattenStates` method would look something like this:

```js
flattenStates: function (objects) {
  return objects.flatMap( obj => {
    return obj.states.map( (state, index) => {
      return {
        obj: obj,
        state: state,
        index: index,
        key: obj.name + " state " + index
      };
    } );
  } );
}
```

<sup>Compatibility note: [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) are not available on IE or on current stable versions of Edge.  To make this code work on those browsers, you'll need a polyfill.  The new Chromium-based versions of Edge, still in beta as of this writing, do however support both.</sup>

Alternatively, you could simplify the template by moving some logic into the `flattenStates` method:

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- label divs omitted for brevity -->

  <vue-draggable-resizable
    class="inner"
    v-for="wrapper in flattenStates(nestedObj.data)"
    :key="wrapper.title"
    :resizable="false"
    :w="100"
    :h="50"
    :parent="true"
  >
    <div>
      <b>{{ wrapper.title }}</b>
      <br />
      <status-indicator :status="wrapper.status" />
    </div>
  </vue-draggable-resizable>
</div>
```

```js
flattenStates: function (objects) {
  return objects.flatMap( obj => {
    return obj.states.map( (state, index) => {
      const wrapper = {
        title: `Bit-${index} of ${obj.name}`  // also used as :key
      };

      if (obj.contentType === 'TypeA') {
        wrapper.status = (state ? 'positive' : 'negative');
      } else {
        wrapper.status = (state ? 'active' : 'intermediary');
      }

      return wrapper;
    } );
  } );
}
```

...or even:

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- label divs omitted for brevity -->

  <vue-draggable-resizable
    class="inner"
    v-for="(status, title) in flattenStates(nestedObj.data)"
    :key="title"
    :resizable="false"
    :w="100"
    :h="50"
    :parent="true"
  >
    <div>
      <b>{{ title }}</b>
      <br />
      <status-indicator :status="status" />
    </div>
  </vue-draggable-resizable>
</div>
```

```js
flattenStates: function (objects) {
  const objStates = {};
  for (const obj of objects) {
    obj.states.forEach( (state, index) => {
      const title = `Bit-${index} of ${obj.name}`;

      if (obj.contentType === 'TypeA') {
        objStates[title] = (state ? 'positive' : 'negative');
      } else {
        objStates[title] = (state ? 'active' : 'intermediary');
      }
    } );
  }
  return objStates;
}
```

Comment: I've tested what you've provided and it's very pleasing to look at honestly. Thank you! ... Also it works, so yay!

Answer (score 2):

Try using CSS `display:contents` on the `outer` element. This [display property](https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/) basically makes the element "invisible" to the browser.

---

However, I think you'd be better off by refactoring your Vue template to remove the outer element. For example, you could process the objects array to combine its children before doing the loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine its children before doing the loop"?

Comment: See @IlmariKaronen's answer for what I mean.

Comment: Oh. Yea, I see where it's going. I guess refactoring is probably the best approach. Since @IlmariKaronen's answer is also covering that I'm gonna accept that.